# Archive Data from Cosmos DB - Mongo DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

in the project i am working on, we have a database per tenant and each tenant consists of at least 1 department. One of the requirements we have is that when an admin user deletes a department using a custom frontend we've provided, the system should first archive the data of that department on a blob storage before the data is deleted. The same we have for the tenant, we need to archive the data before the database of that tenant is removed from the account.

Now, my question: is there any best practice to do this? We are planning to retrieve all the data  from all collections, using a mongo query, based on the department id (which is also the partition key) and then send it to a blob storage. The challenge we have is the execution of the query to retrieve all the data because it can be a huge amount and the RUs required for that action may affect the performance of the system because other users may be using the system while we remove the data.

I looked at mongodump and mongoexport but these are applications so we cannot execute it from our code?

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You *can* call command-line tools from an app - and `mongoexport` / `mongodump` really your only options for now, aside from some custom code. And how you do that is really up to you. There is no built-in export/import for the MongoDB API.

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to solve this is by using [`ChangeFeed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed), as it reallyhelps and  simplifies writing a carbon copy somewhere else.

However, as of now the change feed processor  won't notify you for deleted documents so you can't listen for them, this feature is [planned as of now](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/14603412-execute-a-procedure-when-ttl-expires).

Your best bet is to write some custom application that does archiving using [Query language support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support-36#query-language-support)

Comment: Those stored procedures and UDFs are specific to the core (sql) api and don't apply to the MongoDB API. Also, stored procedures are scoped to partitions, and wouldn't help when trying to export a database.